# How do I remove multiple words from a strting in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I know that how do I remove a single word. But I can't remove multiple words. Can you help me?
This is my string and I want to remove "Color:", "Ring size:" and "Personalization:".

`string = "Color:Silver,Ring size:6 3/4 US,Personalization:J"`

I know that how do I remove a single word. But I can't remove multiple words. I want to remove "Color:", "Ring size:" and "Personalization:"

Comment: Did you try creating a list of words to remove and looping over it? Basically each time you want to do something multiple times use loop (and inside it do it one time, which you know).

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Rather than looking at it as removing the parts you don't want, you could approach it as extracting the parts you do want as a new string.

Comment: Instead of removing words if you just want the values why don't you split the string using : and , and then you take the data from indexes 1,3 and 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a good job for a regex.

Specific case:

```
import re

out = re.sub(r'(Color|Ring size|Personalization):', '', string)
```

Generic case (any word before `:`):

```
import re

out = re.sub(r'[^:,]+:', '', string)
```

Output: `'Silver,6 3/4 US,J'`

Regex:

```
[^:,]+   # any character but , or :
:        # followed by :
```

replace with empty string (= delete)

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = "Color:Silver,Ring size:6 3/4 US,Personalization:J"
def remove_words(string: str, words: list[str]) -> str:
    for word in words:
        string = string.replace(word, "")
    return string

new_string = remove_words(string, ["Color:", "Ring size:", "Personalization:"])
```

Alternative:

```py
string = "Color:Silver,Ring size:6 3/4 US,Personalization:J"
new_string = string.replace("Color:", "").replace("Ring size:", "").replace("Personalization:", "")
```